# how to easily replicate mysql database to and from google-cloud-sql?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

Google says **NO triggers**, **NO stored procedures**, **No views**. This means the only thing I can dump (or import) is just a `SHOW TABLES` and `SELECT * FROM XXX`? (!!!).

Which means for a database with 10 tables and 100 triggers, stored procedures and views I have to recreate, by hand, almost everything? (either for import or for export).

(My boss thinks I am tricking him. He cannot understand how previous, to me, employers did that replication to a bunch of computers using two clicks and I personally need hours (or even days) to do this with an internet giant like Google.)

**EDIT**:

We have applications which are being created in local computers, where we use our local MySQL. These applications use MySQL DB's which consist, say, from n tables and 10*n triggers. For the moment we cannot even check google-cloud-sql since that means almost everything (except the n almost empty tables) must be "uploaded" by hand. And we cannot also check using google-cloud-sql DB since that means almost everything (except the n almost empty tables) must be "downloaded" by hand.

Until now we do these "up-down"-loads by taking a decent mysqldump from the local or the "cloud" MySQL.

Comment: @ Raymond Nijland this is a comment, not the question... Any way, feel free to remove it if not of any usage.

Comment: *"employers did that replication to a bunch of computers using two click"* If you use MySQL on the Google cloud also you can setup [Private IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip) / [Connection options for external applications](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/external-connection-methods) and synchronize your (local/remote) database with a SQL IDE remotely..

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you are asking for. Do you want "replication" or "backups" because these are different concepts in MySQL.

If you want to replicate data to another MySQL instance, you can set up [replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html). This replication can be from a Cloud SQL instance, or to a Cloud SQL instance using the [external master](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/replication-from-external) feature.

If you want to backup data to or from the server, checkout these pages on [importing data](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting) and [exporting data](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing).

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understood, you want to [Create Cloud SQL Replicas](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/). There are a bunch of replica options found in the doc, use the one that fits the best to you.

However, if you said "replica" as [Cloning a Cloud SQL instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/clone-instance), you can follow the steps to clone your instance in a new and independent instance.

Some of these tutorials are done by using the GCP Console and can be scheduled.

Comment: Cloning a Cloud SQL instance is the exact page that says: **Your SQL dump file must not contain any triggers, views, or stored procedures**

Comment: Maybe you should consider to change your design. I would suggest you to put SQL clients on each machine. Make them connect to the same Cloud SQL instance and for each project create a DataBase with the appropriate privileges, triggers and views. Doing this will prevent you to do the view and triggers importation by hand on each machine, since they will live within your Cloud SQL instance.